# NodeJS bidirectional (internal) events

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've made a simple class that receives HTTP GET requests and emits the pathname and query in a event.

The idea is that one can do a get request like: 'example.com/lightControl?id=1&state=true' to set a light on.

However, one should also be able to request the current state of the lamp by simply doing a request like: 'example.com/lightControl?id=1'

```
let http = require('http');
let url = require('url');
let EventEmitter = require("events").EventEmitter;

class Api extends EventEmitter{
    constructor(port){
    super();
    this.startServer(port);
    }
  startServer(port){
    this.server = http.createServer(this.handleRequest);
    this.server.listen(port, function(){
      //Callback triggered when server is successfully listening. Hurray!
      console.log("Server listening on port:", port);
    });
  }
  handleRequest(request, response){
    //console.log("URL",request.url);
    var parsed = url.parse(request.url,true);
    this.emit('request',parsed.pathname,parsed.query);
    response.end('API called: \n\nPath:   ' + JSON.stringify(parsed.pathname) + "\nValues: " + JSON.stringify(parsed.query));
  }   
}
```

Currently my code responds to the request, by stating the pathname and query. But I would like it to respond with the actual status of the light.

The problem however, is that I'm using an event bus. All connected devices can send events and then another device can act upon it, but there is no direct response message. Theoretically, it could send a response event, but then I'll need a way to jump back into the handleRequest function and finish it from where the event was emitted?

I'm thinking that asynchronous and loosely coupled properties of an event bus do not really support such a requirement.

I could go around and do something like this (see below), but that would break the whole principle of a message bus.

```
handleRequest(request, response){
    //console.log('URL',request.url);
    var parsed = url.parse(request.url,true);
    deviceHandler.setDevice(parsed.pathname,parsed.query);
    var state = deviceHandler.getDeviceState(parsed.pathname);
    response.end('Device: ' + parsed.pathname + ' is now: ' + state);
  }
```

Is there a way to achieve this using events?

Or do I require another design?

Comment: This is a really nice asked question! Have a look for "express", which gives you a really nice ability to create routers, especially for POST (setting the value) and GET (get the value). Your idea is well thought, but it might be kinda overkill.

Comment: @Mijago Hmm, not completely related, but you could use GET to set variables as well? I'm more of an embedded/hardware programmer as a web developer. The only reason I can find is since post can avoid weird urlencoding? But I feel GET requests are better supported/easier to make. For example, I have a phone widget that can make GET requests, but I don't believe it does POST requests, which makes me believe setting lighting with GET should be supported in my system (maybe even GET and POST, and parse it to an abstract "event")?

Comment: @Mijago and for one device, yes it's probably overkill, but I would like to make a home automation system, where other devices (for example timers, webservices, a web app) can also push events into an event bus. Coupling them all by calling the function of a "deviceHandler" may be a bit too "tight".

Comment: Yes you CAN use GET for everything, but if you want to build a `correct` HTML-API, have a look for "REST". Your api does not need to be full REST conform, but it is really helpful to use GET to get data, POST to set data, DELETE to delete data and so on. GET is not meant to set anything. With "it might be kinda overkill" i mean that you write your own api-router. express can handle this for you and is well tested.

Also, the difference between the Words is really small, if you look at the http control headers.

Comment: Ah ok, I should do GET to get and POST to set because it's more of a convention/standard? And I did look at "express", but any request will typically translate to an event directly (each route has the same action) so I'm not sure why it would need a router? I'm not trying to serve different pages. (I'm sorry if I sound a bit skeptical/annoying, usually I try not to rely on too much external frameworks/libraries/ideas, especially not when knowing why)